# Errors Displaying Smallest to Largest amount of Inventory Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Alright so basically I made a vending machine program. When the user buys an item equal to or greater than its cost, the inventory of the item will deplete by 1. The item van be bought up to three times, until the stock has ran out. At that point, the JButton will dissapear and the item can not be clicked on or bought. To add complexiity, I added a "Check Total Inventory" button. What is supposed to happen when clicked on, is the program prints out smallest to greatest the amount of stock.

For instance:

```
Inventory of Liton: 0
Inventory of Fanta: 1
Inventory of Pepsi: 2 
Inventory of Gum: 3
Inventory of Seeds:3
Inventory of Chocolate: 3
```

To do that here is the loop I used: 
  private void CheckInventoryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    int inventory[]={stock, stock2, stock3, stock4, stock5, stock6};     

    int temp;
    boolean fixed= false;

    while(fixed==false){
        fixed=true;

         for (int i=0; i<inventory.length-1; i++){
            if(inventory[i]> inventory[i+1]){                    
                temp= inventory[i+1];                    
                inventory [i+1]= inventory[i];                   
                inventory[i]= temp;
                fixed= false;

            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<inventory.length; i++){
            System.out.println("The inventory of Lipton is:" + inventory[i]);
           System.out.println("The inventory of Fanta is:" + inventory[i+2]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Pepsi is:" +inventory[i+3]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Gum is:" +inventory[i+4]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Seeds is:" +inventory[i+5]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Choco is:" +inventory[i+6]);   
    }
}
```

There are a few issues though... I was wondering, if someone could please help me because I do not kow what the problem is, depsite numerous attempts to fix it. When I click only on Fanta and purchase one, (so Fanta inventory should be 2), the inventory for Lipton decreases when I did not click on it. "The inventory of Chocolate: and the number of inventory" does not also print. There are also a lot of other errors such as

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at finalvending.finalvendingclass.CheckInventoryActionPerformed(finalvendingclass.java:623)
at finalvending.finalvendingclass.access$600(finalvendingclass.java:18)
at finalvending.finalvendingclass$7.actionPerformed(finalvendingclass.java:129)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
```

etc.

I do not what these errors are telling me. But I have done a few things to try to remedy this. First, I have running the debug feature to which nothing was found. I have double checked each int stock, int stock2, int stock3, etc. is properly defined for each section above the loop,  etc.

Here is the code I use for each section of what you can buy in the vending machine. Basically each item is copy and paste, except I change the price, and image being called: I can also paste more code if anymore is needed.  Lipton and Fanta:

```
int stock=3;
private void liptonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

DecimalFormat dollarFormat = new DecimalFormat(" $#,##0.00");

String inputstring;
double input, change;

inputstring= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your payment: $");
input= Double.parseDouble(inputstring);
change= input-1;   

    if (input<1)
    {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, " You do not have enough money to purchase this item", "INSUFFICIENT FUNDS",
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); 
    }

    else if (input>1)
    {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You have purchased a Lipton Tea. Here is your change:" +(dollarFormat.format(change)));
    stock--;


    ImageIcon liptonIcon= new ImageIcon("usethislipton.png");

    Image liptonImage= liptonIcon.getImage();
    Image modifiedliptonImage= liptonImage.getScaledInstance(100,150, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    liptonIcon= new ImageIcon (modifiedliptonImage);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Lipton Tea", "Here is your drink! Enjoy!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, liptonIcon);   

    }

    else if (input==1)
    {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You have purchased a Lipton Tea.");
    stock--;

    ImageIcon liptonIcon= new ImageIcon("usethislipton.png");

    Image liptonImage= liptonIcon.getImage();
    Image modifiedliptonImage= liptonImage.getScaledInstance(100,150, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    liptonIcon= new ImageIcon (modifiedliptonImage);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Lipton Tea", "Here is your drink! Enjoy", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, liptonIcon);  
    }

        if (stock==1)
        {    
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, " There is only 1 Lipton Tea remaining! Restock recommnended", "WARNING",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);       
        } 
        else if (stock==0)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Sorry, Lipton Tea is out of stock", "",
           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);       

           lipton.setVisible(false);
        }

}                                      
int stock2=3;
private void fantaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
     final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
     DecimalFormat dollarFormat = new DecimalFormat(" $#,##0.00");

String inputstring;

double input, change;

inputstring= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your payment: $");
input= Double.parseDouble(inputstring);
change= (input-1.25);

if (input<1.25)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, " You do not have enough money to purchase this item", "INSUFFICIENT FUNDS",
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}

else if (input>1.25)
{
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You have purchased a Fanta. Here is your change" +(dollarFormat.format(change)));
       stock2--;

    ImageIcon fantaIcon= new ImageIcon("finalfanta2.png");

 Image fantaImage= fantaIcon.getImage();
 Image modifiedfantaImage= fantaImage.getScaledInstance(100,150, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
 fantaIcon= new ImageIcon (modifiedfantaImage);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Fanta", "Here is your drink! Enjoy", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, fantaIcon);  

}
else if (input==1.25)
{
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You have purchased a Fanta.");
       stock2--;

   ImageIcon fantaIcon= new ImageIcon("finalfanta2.png");

 Image fantaImage= fantaIcon.getImage();
 Image modifiedfantaImage= fantaImage.getScaledInstance(100,150, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
 fantaIcon= new ImageIcon (modifiedfantaImage);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Fanta", "Here is your drink! Enjoy", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, fantaIcon);  

 }

    if (stock2==1)
        {    
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, " There is only 1 Fanta remaining! Restock recommnended", "WARNING",
           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);             
        }
       else if (stock2==0)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Sorry, Fanta is out of stock", "",
           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);       

           fanta.setVisible(false);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping all array and getting the next position for compare, when you are in the end of array and go to the next position you get the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

```
for (int i=0; i<inventory.length-1; i++){
            if(inventory[i]> inventory[i+1]){ //here                   
                temp= inventory[i+1];                    
                inventory [i+1]= inventory[i];                   
                inventory[i]= temp;
                fixed= false;

            }
        }
```

when you solve this, next step is check the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<inventory.length; i++){
            System.out.println("The inventory of Lipton is:" + inventory[i]);
           System.out.println("The inventory of Fanta is:" + inventory[i+2]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Pepsi is:" +inventory[i+3]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Gum is:" +inventory[i+4]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Seeds is:" +inventory[i+5]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Choco is:" +inventory[i+6]);   
    }
```

You are doing the same mistake (check that i + x)

Which version of java are you using?

Comment: Ok thank you! I have been thinking it over the past day or so, sorry for the delayed response. I have been trying to fix the first issue you are discussing but I am still thinking it over on how to fix it... As for the inventory[i], I fixed so Fanat says "" + inventory[1+1], Pepsi inventory [i+2], etc. I was accidentally skipping over the first postition which is why the Fana and Lipton stocks were changing when it was printng.  I am using Netbeans:Version 8.2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, look at this piece of code here:

```
for (int i=0; i<inventory.length; i++){
            System.out.println("The inventory of Lipton is:" + inventory[i]);
           System.out.println("The inventory of Fanta is:" + inventory[i+2]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Pepsi is:" +inventory[i+3]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Gum is:" +inventory[i+4]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Seeds is:" +inventory[i+5]);
                System.out.println("The inventory of Choco is:" +inventory[i+6]);   
    }
```

The variable 'i' will go from 0 to inventory.length-1, inclusive. For instance, take the most extreme case where

```
i = inventory.length()-1
```

Now, lets see what your program will do.

It first starts by printing

```
The inventory of Liptop is: inventory[inventory.length-1]
```

Nothing wrong here. However, the next line is where your programs starts to fail.

`i+2` would be `inventory.length+1`! Obviously, this is out of the array index of inventory.

Comment: Hey Chris! Thank you for the response. I am sorry, I am bit confused by your answer. So after posting, I noticed that my i + X under the for loop were calling the wrong postitions, So i changed so that Fanta [inventory i+1] rather than i +2. I think if I was reading your post right, I did this:

Comment: I'm not sure how to put that in code from, so sorry its condensed. Anyway, that still throws an ArrayOutofboundsexception:6. I probably just misunderstood what you meant, could you please disscuss more in detail why we are changing i

Comment: ` for (int i=inventory.length-1; i<inventory.length; i++){
            s.o.pln("The inventory of Lipton is:" + inventory[inventory.length-1]);
           ("The inventory of Fanta is:" + inventory[inventory.length+1]);
               ("The inventory of Pepsi is:" +inventory[inventory.length+2]);
                ("The inventory of Gum is:" +inventory[inventory.length+3]);
                ("The inventory of Seeds is:" +inventory[inventory.length+4]);
                ("The inventory of Choco is:" +inventory[inventory.length+5]);`